# An error occurs when adding a font to the latest tcpdf version

Tags: php, tcpdf

i am using tcpdf in project but not know adding font and Every article I read is for the old version.
i am try adding font uinsg :

```
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('TCPDF/FreeSerifItalic.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
$pdf->SetFont($font, '', 10, '', true);
```

but" error **TCPDF ERROR:** Could not include font definition file:

Comment: thank you but not function addTTFfont error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer for latest version :converter tcpdf

```
    php path/tcpdf/tools/tcpdf_addfont.php -i path/font.ttf
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).